# ways to express a number as a sum of primes

Tags: python

so im stuck in this problem, i want to print all the ways of summing prime numbers equal to a given number n:
so here is my code;

my problem is that i want to have the number in output too if it's prime.
im lost where and how to add the needed code.;(

i mean if n=2, it'll give me an empty list but i want [2] as my output.

```
n = int(input("between 2n75: "))

prime = []
for x in range(2, n+1):
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        prime.append(x)
listprimes = (prime)

#n = int(input("between 2n75: "))
#print(listprimes)

def allways(n, listprimes):
    ways = [[prime] for prime in listprimes]
    new_ways = []
    collected = []

    while ways:
        for way in ways:
            s = sum(way)
            for prime in listprimes:
                if prime >= way[-1]:
                    if s + prime < n:
                        new_ways.append(way + [prime])
                    elif s + prime == n:
                        collected.append(way + [prime])


        ways = new_ways
        new_ways = []
    return collected

print(allways(n, listprimes))
```

Comment: As a brute-force method, you could check whether ```n``` is prime and if so, immediately add the tuple (0,n) to the result list.

Comment: does 3 + 7 = 10 and 7 + 3 = 10 count as 1 way or 2 ways to express 10 as a sum of primes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the following two lines, which collects something like `[2]`, to your `allways` function.

```py
if s == n:
    collected.append(way)
```

Like the following:

```py
def allways(n, listprimes):
    ways = [[prime] for prime in listprimes]
    new_ways = []
    collected = []

    while ways:
        for way in ways:
            s = sum(way)
            if s == n:  # insert this line
                collected.append(way)  # and this line
            for prime in listprimes:
                if prime >= way[-1]:
                    if s + prime < n:
                        new_ways.append(way + [prime])
                    elif s + prime == n:
                        collected.append(way + [prime])


        ways = new_ways
        new_ways = []
    return collected
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
ways = [[prime] for prime in listprimes]
```

to

```
ways = [[]]
```

Note that your code can be optimized in many places.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
n = int(input("between 2n75: "))

prime = []
for x in range(2, n+1):
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        prime.append(x)
listprimes = (prime)

#n = int(input("between 2n75: "))
#print(listprimes)

def allways(n, listprimes):
    ways = [[prime] for prime in listprimes]
    new_ways = []
    collected = []

    while ways:
        for way in ways:
            s = sum(way)
            if s == prime:
                collected.append(way)
            for prime in listprimes:
                if prime >= way[-1]:
                    if s + prime < n:
                        new_ways.append(way + [prime])
                    elif s + prime == n:
                        collected.append(way + [prime])



        ways = new_ways
        new_ways = []
    return collected

print(allways(n, listprimes))
```